# Как создать png текстуру с ресурса в direcx9 приложении и как правильно создать ресурс? directx9

Tags: c++, directx, resources

Хочу в directx9 приложении использовать текстуру с png файла который должен "лежать" в ресурсах. Собственно наверное нужно использовать D3DXCreateTextureFromResource, но проблема в том что нужно ещё получить hSrcModule и pSrcResource, впрочем.. Как?

Answer (score 1):

Дескриптор модуля можно получить вызвав `GetModuleHandleW`, а имя ресурса формируется макросом `MAKEINTRESOURCEW(MY_TEXTURE_RESOURCE_ID)`.

Также замечу, что API DirectX 9 уже устарело и использовать его в 2018 году для новых проектов нет никакого смысла.

Comment: Я явно тут делаю что-то не так.
`LPD3DXSPRITE sprite;
 LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 tex;
 HMODULE rhandle = 
        GetModuleHandle(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1));
 if (FAILED(D3DXCreateTextureFromResource(dev, rhandle, 
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1), &tex))){
  d3dlog("FAILED D3DXCreateTextureFromResource");
  return 1;
 }` ибо просто краш

Comment: @K2Re8 Для `GetModuleHandle` параметром должно быть имя модуля (exe или dll или NULL) в котором содержится ресурс.

Comment: Вот так краш пропал, но выполняется код который в FAILED
`LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 tex;
 HMODULE rhandle = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
 if (FAILED(D3DXCreateTextureFromResource(dev, rhandle, 
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1), &tex))){
  d3dlog("FAILED D3DXCreateTextureFromResource");
  return 1;
 }`

Comment: @K2Re8 А при обработке ошибки стоит инспектировать значение, возвращаемое `D3DXCreateTextureFromResource`, по коду ошибки можно будет понять, что не так.

Comment: Вышло D3DXERR_INVALIDDATA

Comment: Значит ресурс содержит неправильные данные или сам там ресурса неверный. Для png тип ресурса должен быть `RT_RCDATA`

Comment: Удалил ресурс, нажал создать ресурс, выбрал импорт, выбрал png файл. появился файл resource.h
(Имя файла).png (Имя проекта).rc Попробовал запустить, всё та же ошибка.

Comment: @K2Re8 Откройте файл .rc в текстовом редакторе и выставите тип ресурса в `RT_RCDATA`.

Comment: И как это сделать? там ничего похожего или схожего с RT_ нету, есть сходство с типом IDB_PNG1 PNG (Путь к файлу), я так понимаю это менять? если да, то что именно?

Comment: @K2Re8 Тип ресурса - это как раз среднее выражение, и проблема как раз в том, что там стоит `PNG` а не `RT_RCDATA`

Comment: Всё та же проблема.

Comment: Но размер файла увеличивается при добавлении ресурса. на 18кб